# JTable - TableModelEvent only values that changed

Tags: java, swing, listener, cells, tablemodel

The porblem is that even I change cell value to the same exact value it counts as a change. So for example if I double click a cell and don't change its value my program proceeds to write it to the server.

How can I make that only cells that have their values changed, for instance `(x -> y)` write to server. `(x -> x)` do nothing.

Code below:

```
        Misc_Table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

          public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

             int row = e.getFirstRow();
             int col = e.getColumn();

              Doo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try{
                    Object value = model.getValueAt(row, col);

                        int selected = (int) Functions_ComboBox.getSelectedIndex();

                        if(selected == 0){
                            String val = (String) value;
                            int int_Val = Integer.parseInt(val);
                            BackEnd.WriteMultiple_16Bit(unitID, row, int_Val , 1);                      
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MISC,"Wrong number format.");
                    } catch (Exception e2) {    
                    }
                }

              });   
          }
        });
```

Comment: Before you write to the back end, you have to compare the int_Val from the GUI with the current value.  You have to keep all the current values in a 2 dimensional array so you can get the current value by row and column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/).

The `TableCellListener` replaces the TableModelListener and will only generate events when the data has actually changed, not when the editor is stopped. You just provide an `Action` to be invoked when the data changes.

Comment: Thanks it works. But how can I use this with button? Because I need to press button to write new values. Pressing button sends all generated events and not last ones.

Comment: When you press a button the editor is still active. The table only stops editing when you tab or click on a new cell in the table. You need to stop editing of the cell in order for the value to be saved. Check out [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a couple of solutions.